# Creating a chart.js pie without hover zoom

Tags: javascript, chart.js2

I have this code using the latest version of chart.js:

```
// Set chart default options
Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.enabled = false;
Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = 0;

// Create the chart
new Chart($canvas, {
    type: 'pie',
    responsive: true,
    data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [{
            data: [_value, 100-_value],
            backgroundColor: [
                $pieColor,
                'transparent'
            ],
            hoverBorderColor: [
                'transparent',
                'transparent'
            ]
        }]
    }
});
```

How can I get it to stop zooming in a little bit on mouse over like in the docs?

[Chart.js Pie Introduction](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#doughnut-pie-chart-introduction)